# makeSceneTransitionAnimation shows an error when using AndroidX

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

I have following method which works properly when I use `android.support.v4`

```
override fun onClick(movie: Movie, poster: ImageView, name: TextView) {
            val intent = Intent(activity, DetailActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtras(Bundle().apply {
                    putParcelable(EXTRA_MOVIE, movie)
                })
            }
            val activityOptions = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                    requireActivity(),

                    // Now we provide a list of Pair items which contain the view we can transitioning
                    // from, and the name of the view it is transitioning to, in the launched activity
                    Pair<View, String?>(poster, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(poster)),
                    Pair<View, String?>(name, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(name)))

            // Now we can start the Activity, providing the activity options as a bundle
            ActivityCompat.startActivity(requireContext(), intent, activityOptions.toBundle())
        }
```

Now I want to migrate to `androidx.core.app`. for some reason it displays an error on `makeSceneTransitionAnimation` saying that `non of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied`.

Anyone faced with such a problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to change `Pair<View, String?>` to `Pair<View!, String!>!`?

Comment: @MatPag `Pair<View!, String!>!` does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it worked in this way:

```
//Watchout about this import, it is important!!
import androidx.core.util.Pair

//onCreate code avoided here
val testView = ImageView(this)

val activityOptions = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
     MainActivity.this,
     Pair<View, String>(testView, "hi1"),
     Pair<View, String>(testView, "hi2")
)
// ... startActivity code here
```

using those 2 dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1'
```

Comment: I missed : import androidx.core.util.Pair